# How to tell whether a dylib is compiled for 10.6 or 10.5?

Tags: c++, macos

I was trying to use otool but I couldn't find a way to do it. Basically I'd like to know whether a dylib is compiled only for 10.6 or if it supports 10.5.

Thanks,
Rui

Comment: I guess there probably isn't a trivial way... I'll try to have a look at the format.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a 10.6 machine, but did you try looking at the output of "otool -L"?  You may be able to tell by the version of libSystem against which it's linked.

Comment: Chris is correct:
10.6(.2)'s libSystem appears to be version 125.0.0;
10.5(.8)'s libSystem appears to be version 111.1.4;

Comment: Although this won't tell you if something compiled against the 10.6 libSystem won't still run on 10.5…

Comment: To be 100% sure you'd have to dump out the symbols (nm) and look for any 10.6 only APIs.